# Keep largest & smallest elements in each row of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I am trying to keep the highest and lowest values in each row of a matrix using Matlab. For example, I have the initial matrix:

```
A=
[-6 1   3   9   2   -1;
3   -3  6   5   0   -8;
5   10  9   3   2   1;
20  2   -1  4   9   -4;
4   6   -2  2   7   9;
10  5   -3  3   1   4]
```

and I need to keep the largest & smallest elements in each row of the matrix (let's say 2 largest and 2 smallest), so that the final matrix looks like this:

```
B=
[-6 0   3   9   0   -1;
0   -3  6   5   0   -8;
0   10  9   0   2   1;
20  0   -1  0   9   -4;
0   0   -2  2   7   9;
10  5   -3  0   1   0]
```

I tried `sort` along with `ismember` but without any luck.

How can I keep the largest & smallest elements in each row of the input matrix, and remove the rest of the elements in each row?

Comment: I just submitted an edit to the question, so hopefully that goes through and the intent of question is much clearer. That being said, @Sardar_Usama I believe that you're right - they want to keep the highest & lowest values in each row of the matrix, and remove the rest of the values in each row. In the example final matrix the OP provided, the 2 largest & 2 smallest values in each row of the matrix are kept, while the rest of the values in each row are replaced with a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). Probably not very efficient.

Let your data be defined as:

```
A = [ -6     1     3     9     2    -1
       3    -3     6     5     0    -8
       5    10     9     3     2     1
      20     2    -1     4     9    -4
       4     6    -2     2     7     9
      10     5    -3     3     1     4 ];
m = 2;
M = 2;
```

Then:

```
s = sum(bsxfun(@gt, A, permute(A, [1 3 2])), 3);  % for each element, compute how many
                                                  % elements in its row it exceeds
result = A.*(s<m | s>size(A,2)-M-1);              % apply a mask based on that
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but does seem to be slower. Added performance comparison to my answer.

Comment: @nirvana-msu Yes, as I wrote in my answer, I didn't expect it to be very efficient. But using `bsxfun` here was too tempting :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a very elegant way to do this. We need to use the second output of `sort`, which gives the order of elements across a particular dimension. Caveat is that it gives us the inverse permutation to what we need, so we have to repeat it twice, recursively. All we need then is to set all those elements who's indices are more than `2` and less than `size(A,1)-1` to zero using logical indexing.

Also, note that its much easier to work with numerical matrices, not cells as in your example. You can use `cell2mat` and `num2cell` to convert back and forth if you need to.

```
A = [-6, 1, 3, 9, 2, -1; ...
    3, -3, 6, 5, 0, -8; ...
    5, 10, 9, 3, 2, 1; ...
    20, 2, -1, 4, 9, -4; ...
    4, 6. -2, 2, 7, 9; ...
    10, 5, -3, 3, 1, 4];

[~, idx_inv] = sort(A,2);
[~, idx] = sort(idx_inv,2);
toRemove = idx>2 & (idx<size(A,1)-1);
B = A; B(toRemove) = 0;

>> B
B =
    -6     0     3     9     0    -1
     0    -3     6     5     0    -8
     0    10     9     0     2     1
    20     0    -1     0     9    -4
     0     0    -2     2     7     9
    10     5    -3     0     1     0
```

**EDIT** Comparing performance to the option suggested by @luis-mendo:

```
K>> tic; for t = 1:1e6, [~, idx_inv] = sort(A,2); [~, idx] = sort(idx_inv,2); B = A; B(idx>2 & (idx<size(A,1)-1)) = 0; end; toc;
Elapsed time is 12.379617 seconds.

K>> tic; for t = 1:1e6, s = sum(bsxfun(@gt, A, permute(A, [1 3 2])), 3); B = A.*(s<2 | s>size(A,2)-3); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 17.630724 seconds.
```

This solution using `sort` seems to be ~**1.42x** faster.